# finding the path beyond the bundle

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i want to find the path of the file which is not in my bundle..

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle allBundle] pathForResource:nm ofType:@"jpg" inDirectory:nil];
```

but it gives warning that NSArray may not respond..

is there any way to find the path of file any other folder.

Comment: nm is name of the file..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`allBundle` returns an *NSArray* of all the bundles. You mean to use the method `mainBundle`.

If you can't find your resource then this is most likely a problem with the name of the resource you're looking for (have you checked the value of *nm* is correct?) Also check in your Target under the "Copy resources" section that your .jpg file is listed there. If it's not then you should drag it there to ensure that the file is copied into your bundle when you build it.

If you really want to search through all the available bundles for your resource, then you can loop through the array of bundles that `allBundle` returns as follows:

```
NSString* pathForResource = nil;
for (NSBundle currentBundle in [NSBundle allBundle])
{
    pathForResource = [currentBundle pathForResource:nm ofType:@"jpg"];
    if (pathForResource)
    {
        break; // Found resource, no longer need to search through bundles.
    }
}
```

Note: You also don't need to use the "inDirectory:" part of the method (see the docs).

Comment: But with main bundle i can not find the images beyond of my bundle

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't magically make an `NSArray` respond to methods meant for `NSBundle`. What you have to do is use a `for (... in ...)` loop to loop through the `NSBundle`s contained within the `NSArray` and call the method on each of them.

Comment: I've edited my answer, which also reflects what Douwe has said!